# typescript interface - class implementation without parameter

Tags: typescript

In typescript i am defining one interface and class which implements that interface.

```
interface II {
p1:string;
m1(p:number):string;
}

class A implements II {
    p1;             //??? why data type is not required?
    m1() {         // ??? why it is working even without parameter p
       return "return string"
   }
}
```

Comment: p1 doesn't require a type because it is inferred from the interface.
Try and set `p1 = 1` and you will get an error.

Comment: @TSR It's implicit `any`, not inferred `string`. But yes, it will throw an error because it's incompatible with interface.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, not really a dupe, I retracted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed because when checking function compatibility typescript will allow an implementing function to specify fewer parameters. If the caller specifies the extra parameters they will just be ignored by the function with fewer parameters and no harm will come of it. This is a common scenario in Javscript, consider the `map` function for example:

```
[1].map(v=> v+1); // a function with just one param is fine
[1].map((v, i)=> v + i); // but also one with two
```

You can read more about type compatibility in typescript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the explanations. It helped me to understand how interface works and how it is negligible when converted into JS.

Answer (score 0):

[Typescript uses a structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) and not a nominal type system. This means that if the implementation is safe to call using the declaration, then the typescript compiler will not complain.

In this case, the extra parameters will be [ignored at runtime](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).